# Excel SQL to switch names from First / Last to Last / First

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I have a macro manipulating data.  One of the columns is "NAME" and currently displays names as First / Last, like below.

| NAME |
| --- |
| Mike Smith |
| Bob Jones |
| Barry White |
| Luis De Perez |
| Maria Rodriguez Gonzalez |

I need to update the "NAME" column in the results so the "NAME" column is LAST, FIRST, like below.

| LAST | FIRST |
| --- | --- |
| SMITH | MIKE |
| JONES | BOB |
| WHITE | BARRY |
| DE PEREZ | LUIS |
| RODRIGUEZ GONZALEZ | MARIA |

I'm having trouble writing a SQL statement to accomplish this change.  I'm currently doing this line by line with VBA but this is the slowest part of the process.  I thought using SQL may be faster.

If possible, the SQL statement should:

- Split the "NAME" field on the first "space"
- Switch the "NAME" from First / Last to Last, First
- Change names to UPPER case.  The original data is in both UPPER and LOWER case
- Add a comma between the last and first names

I don't write SQL very often and when I do it's usually simple SELECT statements.  I'm not sure if this is even possible to do in a single SQL.  If 2 SQLs are needed to accomplish this, that would be okay as well as I'm a bit in over my head on this one.

The names are in the "NAME" field in the source data and results.

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions.

Comment: Hopefully you don't plan to store names for people like `Francis Ford Coppola` in your table.  If you have just a space as the separator, you're basically doomed -- some names will get broken.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a helper column and then paste special values:

```
=mid(A1,find(" ",A1,1)+1,50) for the Family name

=left(A1,find(" ",A1,1)-1 for the first name
```

I would do this straight in excel, but you can adapt to what you want.

The 50 in the mid() may need adjusting if there are some very long names.

You could also use proper() to capitalize as needed - but if you prefer ALL CAPS...

Answer (score 0):

With Data as below:

[image]

Formula in cell B2

`=UPPER(MID(A2,FIND(" ",A2,1)+1,LEN(A2)))`

Formula in cell C2

`=UPPER(LEFT(A2,FIND(" ",A2,1)-1))`

Copy down as much required.

Answer (score 0):

Using T-SQL you can do it as follows :

```
select SUBSTRING(NAME, patindex('% %',NAME),LEN(NAME)) as Last_Name,
       substring(NAME,1,PATINDEX('% %',NAME)) as First_name
from mytable
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/2yaE313o)